# Unable to sign in to Windows 11 due to failed sign in attempts

Tags: windows-11

Recently, when trying to sign in to Windows, I get prompted to enter a challenge phrase and then the PIN. When I enter the PIN, I get the following error "This sign-in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempts or repeated shutdowns. Use a different sign-in option, or keep your device powered on for at least 2 hours and then try again.". I have **waited for more than 2 hours** several times to no avail. **I have tried resetting the PIN**, but there is **no option shown**. There are **no other accounts** I can access in the system.

Comment: You should still have access to a password. You can also enable the built-in Administrator account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was due to the account **PIN**. The solution is to delete the `Ngc` folder located at `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\`. If you have access to another Administrator account in the system, this is pretty straightforward.

First, you need to take ownership of the Ngc folder by running `takeown /f C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc /r /d y` on an elevated command prompt. After that, just delete the folder and reboot.

If you do not have access to another account, you need to enable the default administrator user. I did this using `chntpw` on a live Ubuntu USB.

First, boot to Ubuntu from a USB/CD. Open a terminal and run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` to enable the universe repository. Then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install chntpw` to install the `chntpw` package. Now cd into `Windows/System32/config` on the mounted windows NTFS partition (it must be mounted as read-write for this to work, if it isn't due to system hibernation, refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/964402/is-there-anyway-to-unlock-hibernated-ntfs-partition)). Run `chntpw -l SAM` in this directory to list the users. Then run `chntpw -u <username> SAM`, replacing username with the admin username. Select the 2nd option to enable the account and enter `q` and `y` to exit and save the account. You can verify it has been unlocked by running `chntpw -l SAM` again. If it hasn't it may be because the partition has been mounted as read-only.

Once the administrator account has been enabled, boot into Windows. Sign in to the administrator account and follow the steps above to remove the `Ngc` folder.